# Notepad++ find value with regex and replace to value that find with another regex

Tags: regex, windows, notepad++

i have a string:

```
...some values...<id1>10052023</id1>...some others...<id2>306689461795</id2>...
```

i need to replace value between id1 with value from id2, is it possible to do with npp?

i know about groups but i don't know how to use it properly in this case.

my value can be found and stored in group 1 with regex like this:

```
^.*<id1>(.*)</id1>.*$
```

am i right?

Comment: Do you have access to Unix or GNU tools such as `sed`?

Comment: If it's HTML/XML, there's proper parser, like xmlstarlet or xidel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [`xmlstarlet`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xmlstar/) (available on all platforms):

```
$ cat file
<root>
...some values...<id1>10052023</id1>...some others...<id2>306689461795</id2>...
</root>
```

```
$ xmlstarlet edit -d '//id1/text()' -u '//id1' -x '//id2/text()' file
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
...some values...<id1>306689461795</id1>...some others...<id2>306689461795</id2>...
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @Gilles Quénot is correct and may be the best for this case, but does't help someone searching for something that does what the title says.

So here is my, pretty simple, example that might fail in a lot of cases, depending on the XML content.

If you have numbers for the searched placeholders, you can rebuild in your desired order. So I place every area in brackets:

### Solution1 `replace value between id1 with value from id2`

```
Search: <id1>(.*?)</id1>(.*?)<id2>(.*?)</id2>
Replace: <id1>\3</id1>\2<id2>\3</id2>
```

So the result looks like

```
...some values...<id1>306689461795</id1>...some others...<id2>306689461795</id2>...
```

### Solution2 `switch value id1 with value from id2`

```
Search: <id1>(.*?)</id1>(.*?)<id2>(.*?)</id2>
Replace: <id1>\3</id1>\2<id2>\1</id2>
```

So the result looks like

```
...some values...<id1>306689461795</id1>...some others...<id2>10052023</id2>...
```

### Variation when only digits

```
Search: <id1>(\d*)</id1>(.*?)<id2>(\d*)</id2>
Replace: <id1>\3</id1>\2<id2>\1</id2>
```

So the result looks like

```
...some values...<id1>306689461795</id1>...some others...<id2>10052023</id2>...
```